# Openssh 8.0p1 compile error indicating missing 'fd_set' in kludge-fd_set.c

Tags: gnu-make, aix, openssh

OpenSSH is configured to used openssl 3.0.0 and no error was found on configuration. On compile, an error indicating an unknown type name 'fd_set' was raised for the file kludge-fd_set.c:19:27

This is for an AIX 7.1 server that is being customized to run Hadoop. Most of the built-in features have recently been updated and as I rarely do infrastructure software development in C I am not sure which package I should look for/upgrade to get that type.

```
(cd openbsd-compat && make)
gcc -g -O2 -pipe -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-unused-result -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -ftrapv -fno-builtin-memset   -I. -I.. -I. -I./.. -I/usr/local/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -c kludge-fd_set.c
kludge-fd_set.c:19:27: error: unknown type name 'fd_set'
   19 | void kludge_FD_SET(int n, fd_set *set) {
      |                           ^~~~~~
kludge-fd_set.c:22:28: error: unknown type name 'fd_set'
   22 | int kludge_FD_ISSET(int n, fd_set *set) {
      |                            ^~~~~~
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.


Stop.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 2.


Stop.
```

I'm using GCC 9.1 and the installation/compile guide have indicated that this should be an open-and-shut procedure.

Comment: Perhaps somehow symbol `__GNU_LIBRARY__` is defined? It shouldn't be (as AIX is not using glibc), but if it is, you might edit `openbsd-compat/kludge-fd_set.c` to insert after line 14: `#include <sys/time.h>`

Answer (score 1):

The comment from [Lorinczy Zsigmond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141064/lorinczy-zsigmond) was the fix I used to resolve it.